# Broken/missing projection when opening GDB?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I've loaded a GDB Esri in QGIS, however, When I open the layers, those have a different location. I think that the prj file is broken, null or QGIS can't identify correctly.
Anyone have this issue or know how to solve it?

Comment: Different location from what? Different from where they should be? Or different locations for different layers? Where should they be located? Where are they located? Which CRS should they be in? Which are they in?

Comment: Different location form where the should be. For instance the layers's location is Colombia and these appear over the sea

Comment: Geodatabases don't *have* a .prj file. The spatial reference is a part of the feature class definition. It's possible that QGIS can't understand the reference, but then you need to provide what that is.

Comment: Try [assign projection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisassignprojection)

Comment: Indeed, QGIS can't understand the GDB's spatial reference. When execute assign projection, the issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the projection is missing. You can set the projection using [Assign projection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisassignprojection) tool

> ...creates a new layer with the exact same features and geometries as
> the input one, but assigned to a new CRS. The geometries are not
> reprojected, they are just assigned to a different CRS.
>
> This algorithm can be used to repair layers which have been assigned
> an incorrect projection.